# Tomcat Calendar Webapp mysql: MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Guys I have to fix an assessment for my new job. Please not that I am a noob and they are willing to hire me as a trainee, they dont necessary need a complete solution but want to see how I approach this problem. I have to fix a broken webapp (calendar, Java back-end, JS front-end) with the following tools. Maven, Eclipse, Tomcat 9, JDK 1.8 and MYSQL. I fixed the broken Javacode (method not defined) in the webapp already and it is running in tomcat. There is an events.sql file that has some appointments with the dentist etc in it. So obviously these appointments need to appear on the calendar which they dont. I do not have knowledge about mysql so I installed latest version 8.0. I imported the .sql file and the current database is events. In eclipse I tried to connect with the database with Data Source Explorer with Java Connector 5.1.6 and I get the following error code. Is it because of version 8.0? Am i doing the right steps by importing the .sql file and try to connect eclipse with mysql to fix my assessment? Because I am just improvising. http://localhost:3030/events is also not approachable ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**problem**

```
MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication 
protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

**events.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `events`;

CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`start` datetime NOT NULL,
`end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`public` int(1) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`remark` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`option` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

LOCK TABLES `events` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `events` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (49,'Mechanica Beurs','2018-06-20 
08:00:00','2016-06-24 17:00:00',0,'event','',0);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (50,'Tandarts','2018-06-16 10:00:00','2016-06-16 
11:30:00',0,'private','',0);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (51,'Ronald Goedemondt','2018-06-11 
19:00:00','2016-06-11 22:00:00',0,'show','',0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `events` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Connector/J (the JDBC driver for MySQL) is at version 8.0.11. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Yes I checked that out but there is not one available for Windows. Or do I need the platform independent one?

Comment: There's a mysql-connector-java... .jar file in the platform independent download. That's what you want. (I am not sure exactly where to put it so eclipse and tomcat can use it. But you'll surely find the answer by searching.)  Or back off to MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try the connector first. And otherwise I will downgrade to MySQL5.7

Comment: With the 8.0.11 connector I get the error: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'West-Europa (zomertijd)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: Your MySQL server runs on your development machine, it seems. Append `&serverTimezone=Europe/Amsterdam` to your connection string. Read this. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85114

Comment: I tried that it did not work. Although the company already told me that they had to let me know that I needed to use mysql 5.7. Today I have the 2nd conversation and according to their e-mail they are already happy that I got the servlet running on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to mysql 5.7 and added this to context.xml 
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/events?serverTimezone=UTC"